# Using Delphi DLL in Python via ctypes

Tags: python, delphi, ctypes

I have a DLL written in Delphi, but I need to use it in my Python application.

In Delphi it calls easy: `Calc:=CalcCode(@Data, 32, @Num);`

`@Data` and `@Num` are pointers to arrays of Byte:

```
Data: array[0..31] of byte;
Num: array[0..7] of byte;
```

How can I call this function in my Python programm via ctypes?

---

Delphi dll function declaration:

```
function CalcCode(Data: pointer; DataSize: integer; Num: pointer):cardinal; stdcall; external 'CalcCode.dll';
```

Comment: Before you can call it you need to define the interface. You need to show the declaration of the function. Beyond that, do you have any knowledge of ctypes or Delphi? If you do then it should be easy for you to work this out. If you don't have any knowledge then you need to do some independent research and gain that knowledge. Otherwise we might suspect you of just asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: I tried to do it, but there is something wrong:
`class CalcCode(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Data", POINTER(c_ubyte*31)), 
("DataSize", c_int), 
("Num", POINTER(c_ubyte*7))]`

I don't have much experience in ctypes :(
Other functions of this DLL, which don't use pointers, works perfect!
Help me with this function please!

Comment: I don't know PYTHON, but shouldn't **POINTER(c_ubyte*31))** be **POINTER(c_ubyte*32))** and similarly **POINTER(c_ubyte*7))** be **POINTER(c_ubyte*8))**?

Comment: We still don't know what the function declaration is. This stuff matters. Don't keep the details from us. And @Dsm makes a valid point. The length of the arrays are 32 and 8 respectively.

Comment: I'm sorry. 

Here is from Delphi source: `function CalcCode(Data: pointer; DataSize: integer; Num: pointer):cardinal;stdcall; external 'CalcCode.dll'; `

Comment: Please don't include it in a comment. Make an edit to the question.

Comment: Full function code is too big to post here.
@DavidHeffernan, ok, sorry, I'll correct my question soon!

Comment: I don't want to see the full function. We don't need to see the real function. Just a simple stub that demonstrates the problem. My answer shows you how to do that and you might well learn from how I created simple and short demonstration code in that answer. The key concept is the [mcve]. It would be a good exercise for you to fix the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Python code demonstrates how to call that function:

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.WinDLL(dllname)

CalcCode = lib.CalcCode
CalcCode.restype = ctypes.c_uint
CalcCode.argtypes = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte*32), 
    ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte*8)

data = (ctypes.c_byte*32)(*range(32))
num = (ctypes.c_byte*8)()
retval = CalcCode(data, len(data), num)
print retval, list(num)
```

I used this test DLL:

```
library Project1;

function CalcCode(Data: pointer; DataSize: integer; Num: pointer): cardinal; stdcall;
var
  i: Integer;
  P: PByte;
begin
  Result := 0;
  P := PByte(Data);
  for i := 0 to DataSize-1 do begin
    inc(Result, P^);
    inc(P);
  end;
  PInt64(Num)^ := Result*2;
end;

exports
  CalcCode;

begin
end.
```

The output is:

```
496 [-32, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```